# Hide NSwag documentation endpoints based on environment .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, nswag

I am using Nswag for endpoints documentation.

For production we wanted to show only specific methods, so we added `[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` attribute on methods/controllers. However on dev environment we would like to see all of the methods. Is that possible? To show different methods based on environment?